# pyqt QSpinBox отрицательное число

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qspinbox

Не могу найти как заставить QSpinBox работать с отрицательными целыми числами. Учитывая то что в интернете нет даже подобных тем догадываюсь что это не предусмотрено, но какой тогда выход? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Метод setRange: `spin_box.setRange(-100, 100)`? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#setRange

Comment: setMinimum(minimum);
setMaximum(maximum);

Comment: @gil9red В описании есть отрицательные числа, но на практике ниже нуля не опускается. А если передать отрицательное число, то оно превращается в 0.

Comment: @demonplus К сожалению тоже не работает, не позволяет опускать значение ниже нуля, даже если вводишь отрицательное значение в setMinimum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отрицательные числа можно вводить (проверял на PyQt5 5.15.0)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSpinBox

app = QApplication([])

spin_box = QSpinBox()
spin_box.setRange(-100, 100)
spin_box.setValue(-50)
spin_box.show()

app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извиняюсь, была грубая ошибка в моём коде, аж стыдно.

Comment: @arachnoden, бывает, хорошо, что разобрались :)